# Python: create a single dataframe by alternatively include rows from two others

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two pandas of the form:

```
>>> df
                A          B          C
first   62.184209  39.414005  60.716563
second  51.508214  94.354199  16.938342
third   36.081861  39.440953  38.088336
>>> df1
               A         B         C
first   0.828069  0.762570  0.717368
second  0.136098  0.991668  0.547499
third   0.120465  0.546807  0.346949
>>>
```

That I generated with:

```
  import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([3, 3])*100,
columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['first', 'second', 'third'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random([3, 3]),
columns=['A', 'B', 'C'], index=['first', 'second', 'third'])
```

Could you find the smartest and quickest way of getting something like:

```
                A          B          C
first   62.184209  39.414005  60.716563
first_s   0.828069  0.762570  0.717368
second  51.508214  94.354199  16.938342
second_s  0.136098  0.991668  0.547499
third   36.081861  39.440953  38.088336
third_s   0.120465  0.546807  0.346949
```

?

I guess I could do with a for cycle saying take even rows from the first and odd rows from the second but it does not seem very efficient to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [501]: pd.concat([df, df1.set_index(df1.index + '_s')]).sort_index()
Out[501]:
                  A          B          C
first     62.184209  39.414005  60.716563
first_s    0.828069   0.762570   0.717368
second    51.508214  94.354199  16.938342
second_s   0.136098   0.991668   0.547499
third     36.081861  39.440953  38.088336
third_s    0.120465   0.546807   0.346949
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the same result with general labels? Without sorting alphabetically?